# Extracting clock time from string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a dataframe that consists of web-scraped data. One of the fields scraped was a time in clock time, but the scraping process wasn't perfect. Most of the 'good' data look something like `'4:33`, or `'103:20` (so a leading single quote, and two fields, minutes and seconds). Also, there is some bad data, the most common one being `'],`, but also some containing text. I'd like a new string that is something like `4:33`, and for bad data, just blank.

So my plan of attack is to match my good data form, and then replace everything else with a blank space. Sometime like `time <- gsub('[0-9]+:[0-9]+', '', time)`. I know this would replace my pattern with a blank, and I want the opposite, but I'm unsure as to how to negate this whole pattern. A simple carat doesn't seem to work, nor applying it to a group. I tried something like `gsub("(.)+([0-9]+)(:)([0-9]+)", "\\2\\3\\4", time)` but that isn't working either.

Sample:

```
dput(sample)
c("'], ", "' Ling (2-0)vsThe Dragon(2-0)", "'8:18", "'13:33", 
"'43:33")
```

Expected output:

```
c("", "", "8:18", "13:33", "43:33")
```

Comment: Can you show some example data

Comment: Sorry, sample included.

Comment: It's okay.  Based on the `sample`, if you want only the last three elements, use `grep` i.e. `grep(':', sample, value=TRUE)` or if you need `NA` values for the first three, `library(stringr); str_extract(sample, '\\d+:\\d+')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grep` to replace the elements that do not follow the pattern to `''` and then replace the quotes (`'`) with `''`.  Here, the pattern is the strings that start (`^`) with `'` followed by numbers, `:`, numbers in that order to the end (`$`) of the string.  So, all other string elements (by negating i.e. `!`) are assigned to `''` using the logical index from `grepl` and we use `sub` to replace the `'`.

```
 sample[!grepl("^'\\d+:\\d+$", sample)] <- ''
 sub("'", '', sample)
 #[1] ""      ""      "8:18"  "13:33" "43:33"
```

Or we can also do this in one step using `gsub` by replacing all those characters (`.`) that do not follow the pattern `\\d+:\\d+` with `''`.

```
 gsub("(\\d+:\\d+)(*SKIP)(*F)|.", '', sample, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] ""      ""      "8:18"  "13:33" "43:33"
```

Or another option is `str_extract` from `library(stringr)`.  It is not clear whether there are other patterns such as `"some text '08:20 value"` in the OP's original dataset or not.  The `str_extract` will also extract those time values, if present.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(sample, '\\d+:\\d+')
#[1] NA      NA      "8:18"  "13:33" "43:33"
```

It will give `NA` instead of `''` for those that doesn't follow the pattern.

Comment: Thank you, this is probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sub`:

```
sub('.+?(?=[0-9]+:[0-9]+)|.+', '', sample, perl = TRUE)
[1] ""      ""      "8:18"  "13:33" "43:33"
```

The regex consists of two parts that are combined with a logical *or* (`|`).

1. `.+?(?=[0-9]+:[0-9]+)`
   This regex matches a positive number of characters followed by the target pattern.
2. `.+` This regex matches a positive number of characters.

The logic: Replace everything preceding thte target pattern with an empty string (`''`). If there is no target pattern, replace everything with the empty string.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason it cut off the leading digit on the last two examples?

Comment: Wow, this very much changes how I understood regex. I assumed the OR statement acted like a usual OR, as in, in this case, everything that matches the first or second statement would be replaced with ''. Is this not the case?

Comment: @goodtimeslim The second argument is only evaluated if the first one fails.